same pbix on power bi report server scheduled refresh fails and succeeds
I deployed some pbix reports on PBIRS. I created scheduled refresh. My problem is that they sometimes fail and sometimes succeed. I am talking about the same pbix file. The same pbix file fails and succeed. That is why I think it is something about PBIRS. If it was about the pbix file, it wouldn't had refreshed at all.
Also, when I go to
Manage => Scheduled Refresh => Refresh Now
they successfully refresh, some from the first time, some from the second, third or fourth time
I mainly have 3 errors
1- Unable to combine data error.
Exact error syntax
ErrorCode 1055784932 Unable to combine data: xxx references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination
2- Deadlock victim
Exact syntax
ErrorCode 0 Transaction Process ID 71 was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction
3- Report Server Database Unavailable
Exact syntax (there are 2 actually)
3-1- ErrorCode 1056505856 COM error: Microsoft.BIServer.HostingEnvironment, ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException
3-2- ErrorCode 1056505856 COM error: Microsoft.PowerBI.ReportServer.ASEngineManagedRoot, ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException
So why does that happen ?
And is there a way to tell PBIRS to keep refreshing until it reaches a success, just like I do but somehow programmatically ?
Thanks
Manual refresh
Change data source
Reduce power query work
